# Windows XP app not able to talk to web server

Tags: windows, security, firewall, adobe-air

My company makes an app built with Adobe Air which talks to our webserver for user authentication.  Some users are not able to login.  Running Charles Proxy tells us that the "host cannot be found."  Loading up the webserver in IE, initially we weren't able to visit the site, we had to add it to trusted sites.  My guess is that some security setting is denying our app as well.  Does anyone have any suggestions as far as where to make security looser for our app?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be over at serverfault for this one as it sounds more like a network admin type of issue.

Also some details on the network setup would be nice.  Is this site publicly available (i.e. not just on your intranet)?  For which clients does the app work.  Are the working and not working in the same area.  Is it possible that one is wired and the other is wireless.